# Can't assign a value to a variable inside a class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {

    int i;
    int * p = new int;
    *p = 5; // This doesn't worl
    // If I instead use  int * p = new int(5); it works.
};
```

Why that? I see that this only occurs inside a class, if I write the same code on the main function it should work.

Comment: The thing that doesn't work is not valid syntax.

Comment: Because such expressions need to be inside a function.

Comment: One is initialization of `p`, another is assignment to `*p`. Only initialization is allowed outside of block scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax in invalid. You cannot simply write code inside a class definition. Instead, you can write a function and your code will work inside it:

```
class Foo {
public:
  void bar() {
    int * p = new int;
    *p = 5;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  Foo f;
  f.bar();
}
```

**Note:** You should prefer to allocate and initialize your variable in a single statement when possible:

```
int *p = new int(5);
```

Instead of:

```
int * p = new int;
*p = 5;
```

Comment: This does not default-initialize `p`...

Comment: I tried to keep the example as close to the question as possible. Why does it bother you?

Comment: not bothering me :-) But in the case of `int *p = new int(5)`, `p` would be initialized in the course of object construction. In some situations, e.g. when default-initializing a vector of `Foo`-objects, it is very inconvenient to have to call methods after object creation.

Comment: No need to convince me :) I agree with you. I will edit the answer to include a better example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this under the assumption that you need to allocate a member dynamically, and you can't simply pass arguments to its c'tor for whatever reason (that class should be redesigned, but it's another issue).

To execute a couple of statements as part of initializing a variable in the class definition, you can wrap it in a lambda, and call it immediately:

```
class Foo {
    int i;
    int * p = []() {
        auto *ret = new int;
        *ret = 5;
        return ret;
    }(); // <-- Invokes the lambda right away
};
```

Only initialization is allowed at namespace and class scope. Other statements must appear at block scope, which the lambda provides.

But it's messy, ill-advised, and you shouldn't do it unless you really have to. A constructor definition would be better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer StoryTeller. But I'm new to programming, what do you mean by lambda ?

Answer (score 2):

A class definition consists from its member declarations (if the class contains a member). You may not use statements except declarations in class definition.

This statement in your class definition

```
*p = 5; // This doesn't worl
```

is not a declaration. Instead of this two statements

```
int * p = new int;
*p = 5; // This doesn't worl
```

you could write just declaration

```
int * p = new int( 5 );
```

Pay attention to the standard smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` that can be used instead of the raw pointer in your class definition. In this case the memory will be freed automatically when the object ceases its existence. For example

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p{ new int(5) };
```