# Variable declaration only working but not other statements in def of class in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

The below code is working fine & printing `x is: 1`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class class1 {  
    public:  
            class1() {
                    cout << "x is: " << x << endl;
            }
            int x = 1;
};

int main() {class1 obj1;}
```

But the below code isn't

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class class1 {  
    public:  
            class1() {
                    cout << "x is: " << x << endl;
            }
            int x = 1;
            printf("%d", x);
            x++;
};

int main() {class1 obj1;}
```

It is throwing the following error:

```
temp.cpp:11:10: error: expected identifier before string constant
   printf("%d", x);
          ^~~~
temp.cpp:11:10: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
temp.cpp:11:17: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘printf’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   printf("%d", x);
                 ^
temp.cpp:12:3: error: ‘x’ does not name a type
   x++;
   ^
```

My g++ version: (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

My C++ version is: C++14 (cout <<  __cplusplus; returns 201402)

Can someone plz explain what's happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When do you imagine that `printf` would run?  It is not in any function.

Comment: The lines `printf("%d", x);  x++;` are not valid statements inside a class definition. What more information would be useful to you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(object) does not name a type. Whats going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979305/object-does-not-name-a-type-whats-going-on) or [Can't assign a value to a variable inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532074/cant-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-inside-a-class/46532284#46532284)?

Comment: @DrewDormann even if i remove printf statement & keep only `x++;` , I'm getting error.

Comment: @RSahu can you please explain what makes them invalid? Thanks!